# IndexOutOfBounds while looping through 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I apologize if this has been posted before, however I could not find anything specifically related to my problem.

I have a small bit of my code here, I have a 2D array with some information, and I loop through the rooms and columns as shown. This works, and everything is printed out, but I get this error at the end of the loop:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Here is my code:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int data[][] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
                        {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}};

        int x;
        int y;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < data[j].length; j++){
                x = j * 16;
                y = i * 16;
                System.out.println(x + " " + y + " " + data[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `for(int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++)`

Answer (score 0):

Reference ::

int[][] data = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}}; 
  System.out.println(data.length + ", " + data[0].length +
   ", " + data[1].length);

Output= 2, 2, 3